# How to properly mix sounds using Alsa lib on my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pjsip, alsa, pulseaudio

I am creating a VoIP application using my Raspberry Pi 3 and the [PJSIP](https://www.pjsip.org/) Library and I'm not able to play recorded wav sounds while performing a call. (For example my recording sound may be "call initiated" or "call ended"). I need to hear the remote endpoint at the same time.

Currently I can properly hear sounds from the remote endpoint trought the Raspberry Speaker.

I also succeed to play multiple .wav files at the same time using Alsa aplay command. To achieve this, I followed documentation from Software mixing in [alsa documentation](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc)

The blocking point is to play recording sounds while hearing my remote speaker's voice. When I use aplay to manually play my wav sound during one call, it says my device is busy:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Laboratory $ aplay test.wav 
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:828: error opening audio: Device or resource busy
```

Here is my ~/.asoundrc file used to use alsa software mixing:

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmixer"
}

pcm.dmixer  {
        type dmix
        ipc_key 1024
        slave {
                pcm "hw:0,0"
                period_time 0
                period_size 1024
                buffer_size 4096
                rate 44100
        }
        bindings {
                0 0
                1 1
        }
}

ctl.dmixer {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

I investigated on following point:

1. I wonder if my PJSIP application uses properly my alsa "dmixer" plugin. If not, how to force using this plugin ?
2. I am unsure about the sampling rate of 44100 hz defined in asoundrc file. Could it be conflicting with call sample rate ?
3. I am also not at ease with topics as "period time", "period_size", "buffer_size". Might they be wrong values ?
4. Could my wav files be uncompliant with Pjsip Library ? (just an idea)

Comment: It still doesn't work but: I noticed it worked on my old Alsa installation (v1.1.3). As soon I reinstall Alsa library my virtual devices are not detected anymore. So I decided to keep my old Alsa installation and don't touch it anymore. It is weird because I kept the same configuration either in ~/.asoundrc and /etc/asound.conf files...

Comment: I didn't succeed to play sounds via aplay command while alsa was busy during a PJSIP call. However I found a bypass solution : now I play sounds directly in the pjsip library. Imo this solution is way better anyway.